# Removed thousand seperator in Excel currency format

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

we have a big file including a lot of prices in EUR. These columns are format on currency. By doing this Excel automatically creates a , as thousand seperator. This , creates an issue in our file because it sometimes needs to be converted. So my question is. How can the thousand seperator be removed in a currency/accounting formated column in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the thousands separator:

- In the Home pane, Number section, click little button on bottom-right

[image]

- Click on Number
- Clear the "Use 1000 Separator (,)" check box.

The effect is immediate.

Comment: You could also NOT use the currency format.